# rhel7 default gateway in the route table

Tags: linux-networking, gateway, route, rhel7, iproute

After restarting network/rebooting the server, the default gateway IP address is also getting added as a route Destination in `RHEL7`. How can I prevent this? We have not specified this setting and not sure how `RHEL` is picking up and adding this in the route table.

```
[root@server1 ~]$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.23.100.1    0.0.0.0         UG    300    0        0 bond0
0.0.0.0         172.23.100.1    0.0.0.0         UG    301    0        0 bond1
172.23.100.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     300    0        0 bond0
172.23.100.1    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    301    0        0 bond1
172.23.130.23   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    301    0        0 bond1
```

I dont want the last but one entry with Destination "`172.23.100.1`" to be present in the route table. Can someone please help me here?

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is not the route you are speaking about; rather, you have two bond interfaces (`bond0` and `bond1`) on the same network and *both* with a default gateway specified.

This setup is generally discouraged, as:

- only one logical interface (ie: a single `bond`) should be on a given network segment;
- only one gateway should exists.

I strongly suggest you to correct the above issues.

Comment: I would add that combining all of the interfaces forming the two bonds is likely the right solution to this problem.